# Custom actionbar with spinner in center

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am new in android How achieve custom action bar like given image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEIjZ.png)

please help me for making this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use a Toolbar for the action bar.
The toolbar is a ViewGroup which you can add any custom view to it.

example:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <YourViewHere/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

and in your activity :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    // Find the toolbar view inside the activity layout
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    // Sets the Toolbar to act as the ActionBar for this Activity window.
    // Make sure the toolbar exists in the activity and is not null
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```